# Remmina USB redirection

Tags: usb, remote-desktop, remmina

I have been trying to get USB redirection working under **Remmina 1.4.25**.  My client OS is **Linux 5.15.0-60-generic (jammy)**.  My target OS is **Linux 5.4.0-144-generic (focal)** which is running **xrdp/focal,now 0.9.12-1 amd64**.  I have also tested to **Windows 2019 Server**.

I have tested with various devices from thumbdrives to Android phones.  No USB device ever appears at the target ( according to `lsusb` in **Linux** or `Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_.InstanceId -match '^USB' }` in **Windows**).

I ran the Remmina DEBUG page during connection - no errors but no indication it was attempting to forward the USB device either.

I have checked out the [developers site](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina) and [remmina.org](https://www.remmina.org/remmina-rdp) but found no references dealing with configuring this "Advanced" feature of Remmina other than the "mouse-over" help (seen below).  I have tried every syntax I can think of without success.

[image]

I ***have*** successfully forwarded USB using Virtual Machine Manager and SPICE (the targets are mostly QEMU/KVM virtual machines).  But I would greatly prefer to use Remmina-RDP.

Has anyone successfully redirected a usb device using remmina-rdp? Antenore Gatta won't return my calls...

Comment: The [Remmina developers page is here](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina) you may want to ask them, There are some old pages like [one](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2049), [two](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2320), [three](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2504) , [four](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2437).

Comment: Yes, I have been perusing it.  Thanks.  Thinking of reinstalling from their PPA but 1.4.25 is pretty recent already.

Comment: I have a hunch that `xrdp` server (at the remote Ubuntu Desktop) may not have this feature. This [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/vctlyj/xrdp_and_local_usbdevices/) seems to confirm this, though the language of the alternative solution is not clear. I don't have a Windows computer to test if and how it works with the RDP in Windows.

Comment: Quite possible.  But it does not work to a Windows RDS either.  If neither xRDP nor Microsoft support it, what is it there in Remmina for?